# Print Image to file using PrintDocument

Tags: c#, printdocument

I have C# project (ClassLibrary in ASP.NET MVC project)

I want to print an Image (System.Drawing.Image) to file using `PrintDocument`

```
private static void SendToPrinter(Image barkod)
{
    PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
    pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings
    {
        PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer",
        PrintToFile = true,
        PrintFileName = @"D:\f.jpg"
    };

    pd.PrintPage += (o, e) => 
    {
        Point loc = new Point(100, 100);
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(barkod, loc);
    };
    pd.Print();
    barkod.Dispose();
}
```

What is happening is the file is created on the specific location, but when I try to open the image I get error

> Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XPS Document Writer prints in *.xps or *.oxps format.

You need to consider converting xps|oxps to .jpg

change the extesion of file to `xps`

```
PrintFileName = @"D:\f.xps"
```

Comment: I changed the file extension to `xps` and it solved the problem. Thank you

Comment: you may consider to use [print-driver](https://www.print-driver.com). you can add new print driver for jpg.